# Create an MBR Partition on GPT Disk

Tags: partitioning

How do I create an MBR Partition on a GPT Disk ?

When I do the following:

```
select partition 6
convert mbr
```

it tells me:

"The operation is not allowed on a disk that contains a page file"

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MBR and GPT is not partitions' types. MBR stands for master boot record, and while you use MBR, you have old style partition table. Also GPT stands for GUID partition table and is new type of partition table. These two types have different structure and can't be used simultaneously on one phisical disk. Assume that you can only convert the whole disk to MBR table or GPT table and than create new partitions there.

Comment: I thought so. thank you. What would you recommend as a bootable tool (software) to best partition my laptop drive to MBR, since I cannot do it from within windows, since windows is running on the drive I want to format..

Comment: If you will install windows there, you can use installation dvd/usb.  First way: map drive before installing with graphical interface.  Second way: you can press shift+F10 when install media boot and use `diskpart` command line utility for mapping your drive.  First way creates only MBR table.